# Weblogic server installation error

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I launch Oracle installer from the command line. The path is:

*C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar*.

When the installation is complete сonfig.cmd is launching and this apprears in the command line:

> Too long entering line. Unexpected appearance: :process_classpath. C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2017-12-26_12-32-05PM>

Who faced this and knows any solutions to bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm thinking it might be some privilege issue.
2. I had similar kind of issue , so I started the installation in admin mode
3. Instead running from direct java bin path , try to set class path in environment variable then try.